# Java match a single word, that may or may not be separated by spaces

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I want to write a program which reads the following input:

```
<repeat value="2" content="helloworld"/>
```

Now I need to parse and store 'repeat', '2' and 'helloword' in different variables. So far so good. The catch is that there may be whitespaces anywhere in the input, which makes the task significantly harder and out of my capabilities. I thought to maybe use regex, but I couldn't get one working and my research on the topic yielded no result. So what would be a clever way to do this?

Example:

```
< rep eat va lue=" 2"    conte nt= "helloworld"/>
```

To mach

```
repeat, 2, helloworld
```

Comment: this? `(?<=<)(\w+)|\w+="(\w+)"`, [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vE2xQ6/1)

Comment: What exactly do you want to retrieve? The name of the tag and the value of each of its attribute? You most likely would benefit from using an XML parser.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/hU0eE2/1

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex to cover all possible spacings:

```
<\s*(\w+)\s+value\s*=\s*"(\w+)"\s*content\s*=\s*"(\w+)"\s*\/\s*>
```

This will match the entire string you gave as example and return the tag (1st group), value (2nd group) and content (3rd group).

[Test it online at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vF5fN5/1)

---

**Update:**

To even allow spaces inside the keywords `value` and `content`, you can simply add a `\s*` (matches any number of whitespace characters, including zero) between every letter:

```
<\s*(.+)\s+v\s*a\s*l\s*u\s*e\s*=\s*"(\w+)"\s*c\s*o\s*n\s*t\s*e\s*n\s*t\s*=\s*"(.+)"\s*\/\s*>
```

[Test it online at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vF5fN5/2)

Comment: Thanks @ByteCommander, but can we take it one step further - match the words I want to match even if there are whitespaces within them. Editing my question for more clarification.

Comment: @Alex You can add `\s*` between all letters. updated my answer. Also don't forget to accept it if it solves your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use DOM parser, for example [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/). 
Of course, input should be valid xml/html

```
package com.example;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class AttributesReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xmlStrMessage="<repeat value=\"2\" content=\"helloworld\"/>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xmlStrMessage);
        Elements repeat = doc.select("repeat");
        System.out.println("value:"+repeat.attr("value"));
        System.out.println("content:"+repeat.attr("content"));
    }
}
```